# How can I get data from firebase for each element in a Flatlist?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a flatlist that receives eventIds as data. On each renderItem call I want to find the corresponding event-object to each eventId on firebase and render this data. (E.g. title or image from this event)

This is the function to get a single event from firestore based on the eventId:

```
export async function getSingleEventDataFireStore(eventId) {
const db = firebase.firestore();
const eventFirestoreDoc = db.collection("events").doc(eventId);
const doc = await eventFirestoreDoc.get();
if (!doc.exists) {
  console.log("No such Event!");
} else {
  console.log("Event data fetched!");
  return await doc.data();
}
}
```

this is where the flatlist is displayed:

```
const EventScreen = () => {
  const [event, setEvent] = useState([]);
  const [eventFetched, setEventFetched] = useState(false);
  const eventIds = [{id:'1', eventId: 'jaelfmk130'}, {id:'2', eventId: '1jlk335n1'}]

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    if (!eventFetched) {
      firestore.getSingleEventDataFireStore(item.eventId).then((eventItem) => {
        setEvent(eventItem);
        setEventFetched(true);
      });
    }
    setEventFetched(false)
    return ( <View><Text>{event.title}</Text></View> )
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={eventIds}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        renderItem={renderItem}
      />
    </View> )
}
```

This ends up in an infinite loop, because I set eventFetched to false again during renderItem. Otherwise, if I remove setEventFetched(false) it only renders one item.

How can I set eventFetched to false after the render of each item without ending up in a loop?